# Получения всех ID из многомерного массива на PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [parent] => 9
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [11] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 11
                                            [parent] => 10
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, получить все его ID
Т.е. в итоге должно получиться

```
array(9, 10, 11)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обойти рекурсивно и собрать:

```
function getAll($field = 'id', $data) {
    if (empty($data)) return [];
    $res = [];
    foreach ($data as $v) {
        $res[] = $v[$field];
        $res = array_merge($res, getAll($field, $v['children']));
    }
    return $res;
}
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/MNFXO)

> [7,9,10,11,12]

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = [
    7 => ['id' => 7,'parent' => 0,'children' => []],
    9 => ['id' => 9,'parent' => 0,'children' => [
            10 => ['id' => 10, 'parent' => 9, 'children' => [
                11 => ['id' => 11, 'parent' => 10, 'children' => [
                    12 => ['id' => 12, 'parent' => 11, 'children' => [
]]]]]]]]];

$out = [];
array_walk_recursive($in, function($i, $k) use (&$out) { 
    if ($k==='id') $out[] = $i;
});
var_dump($out);
```

[https://3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/00Ts3)